# Study the local minimum, maximum points or saddle points for the function $f(x,y)=xy^2+\sin(x)$ in the region $A = \{(x,y)\mid x\ge 0\}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Study the local minimum, maximum points or saddle points for the function $f(x,y)$ 
where $f(x,y)=xy^2+\sin(x)$
in the region $A = \{(x,y)\mid x\ge 0\}$

my attempt:

$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)(x,y)= y^2+\cos(x) $

$\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right)(x,y)= -\sin(x) $

$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)(x,y)= 2 y x $

$\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)(x,y)= 2 x $

$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x \partial y}\right)(x,y)= 2 y $

to find the critical points :

at
$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)(x,y)= 0 $

$y^2+\cos(x) =0 $  then $ x=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+2\pi n$ , $ x=\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)+2\pi n$ and $y=0$

at
$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)(x,y)= 0 $

$2yx=0 $ then $ x=0 , y=0$

if $\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right)(x,y).\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)(x,y)-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x \partial y}\right)^2(x,y) \gt 0 $ it's a maximum or minimum

if $\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right)(x,y) \gt 0 $ then it's a minimum point

if $\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right)(x,y) \lt 0 $ then it's a maximum point

if $\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\right)(x,y).\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)(x,y)-\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x \partial y}\right)^2(x,y) \lt 0 $ it's a saddle point

My problem is in the critical points. I'm confused.

Comment: If we consider the matrix of the second partial derivatives of $f$ and apply the Sylvester criterion, then it is clear that $\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi n$ is the coordinate of minimum points (by the way, you should indicate that $n=0,1,2,...$), and $\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n$ -- is no minimum points (maybe maximum). But if you look at the points $M_k=(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n,\frac{1}{k})$ for any $k$, it is clear that $f(M_k)>1=f(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n,0)$ and $(\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n,0)$ -- not maximum points.